# Regarding efficiency of passport.js module "deserializeUser" in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

So I was looking into the document regarding passport.js module [serialize](http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password) users to keep logged in users in session. (A little above the Username & Password parts). I'm using mongodb, with mongoose

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log("this code is used again! ");
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

I test these code in example they gave. So it looks that this piece of code is executed every time when the logged-in user refresh a page.

Say there are 100,000 users and there are 10 pages in this entire application, it means there will be 1 million look-ups, just to maintain in session status for every one. Doesn't this sounds too inefficient? Does most application do this kind database search?

Or am I making mistaking understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from using a cache or similar approach. One of them could be https://www.npmjs.com/package/cache-manager but do shop for more!

Alternatively, if you don't really need to know all the user information all the time you can serialize/deserialize the user id only and load the user record on demand. In your instance just pass through function:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   console.log("this code is used again! ");
   done(null, id);
});
```

If that's not enough you could deserialize to an object like this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   console.log("this code is used again! ");
   done(null, {id: id, user: function(done){
       User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
         done(err, user);
       });
   }});
});
```

Comment: well i still need to load user sometimes, is there a way to separate "first time" verification from "second time" session maintain?

Comment: A quick idea is to return an object where first field would be the user id and other field would be a function that returns the user object instance. I'm going to add it to my answer so it's clearer what I mean.